# Add empty rows for gaps between subscriptions

Tags: r, date, addition, rows

I have been struggling with this for a while now and I haven't been able to find a comparable question asked anywhere, hence my first question on here!

I'm fairly new to R so please excuse any obvious errors I have made.

I have a dataset which has a row for each subscription that a user has or has had. Some users have multiple rows, while some others only have one. Only active or previously active subscriptions are present.

I have two variables which state when the subscription has started and when it ended called, Begindate and Enddate respectively. I already have relationlength variables created which state the amount of days between these two variables for each type of subscription. This means that the relationlength variables only give the amount of days for when a subscription was active.

What I would like to do is create empty rows in between the different subscription rows for the time periods in which no subscription was active, starting from the earliest Begindate known for the specific user and ending on a given date where all subscriptions end (20-04-2022).

I have tried to compare the date difference from the first begindate known for a user and the final date and subtracting the relation length known for the other subscription types. However, I could not make this work.

An example of what the df currently looks like:

(rl standing for relationlength)

```
ID Begindate Enddate Subscrtype active rl_fixed rl_promotional Productgroup

1 2019-08-26 2022-04-20 fixed   1      968      0              1
1 2018-08-24 2019-08-23 fixed   0      364      0              1
1 2015-08-24 2016-08-23 promo   0      0        364            2
2 2019-08-26 2019-09-12 fixed   0      17       0              1
2 2018-08-24 2019-08-23 fixed   0      364      0              1
```

What I would like it to look like:

```
ID Begindate Enddate Subscrtype active rl_fixed rl_promo rl_none Productgroup

1 2019-08-26 2022-04-20 fixed   1      968      0        0       1
1 2019-08-24 2019-08-25 none    0      0        0        2       NA
1 2018-08-24 2019-08-23 fixed   0      364      0        0       1
1 2016-08-24 2018-08-23 none    0      0        0        729     NA
1 2015-08-24 2016-08-23 promo   0      0        364      0       2
2 2019-09-13 2022-04-20 none    0      0        0        950     NA
2 2019-08-26 2019-09-12 fixed   0      17       0        0       1
2 2019-08-24 2019-08-25 none    0      0        0        2       NA
2 2018-08-24 2019-08-23 fixed   0      364      0        0       1
```

The end goal is to aggregate and have a clear overview of the specific relation lengths for the different types of relations possible for a user.

Thank you in advance!

dput for one specific user in the real df:

```
structure(list(ï..CRM.relatienummer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), Begindatum = c("2019-08-26", 
"2018-08-24", "2017-08-24", "2016-08-24", "2015-08-20", "2016-06-01"
), Einddatum = c("2022-04-20", "2019-08-23", "2018-08-23", "2017-08-23", 
"2016-05-31", "2016-08-19"), Type.abonnement = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Actie", class = "factor"), Status_dummy = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), relationlength_fixed = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), relationlength_promo = c(968, 
364, 364, 364, 285, 79), relationlength_trial = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), fixed_dummy = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), trial_dummy = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), promotional_dummy = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c("1:20610", 
"2:38646", "2:39231", "2:39232", "2:39248", "2:39837"), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit:

I have tried to run this code:

```
dfs <- split(testdata,testdata$ï..CRM.relatienummer)

r <- lapply(seq(length(dfs)), function(k){
  v <- dfs[[k]]
  vt <- data.frame(unique(v$ï..CRM.relatienummer), 
                   as.character((as.Date(v$Einddatum)+1)[-1]), 
                   as.character((as.Date(v$Begindatum)-1)[-nrow(v)]), 
                   0,
                   0,
                   0,
                   0,
                   (as.Date(v$Begindatum)-1)[-nrow(v)] - (as.Date(v$Einddatum)+1)[-1],
                   NA,
                   0,
                   0,
                   0,
                   0,
                   0)
  colnames(vt) <- c(colnames(v)[-ncol(v)],"rl_none",colnames(v)[ncol(v)])
  (testdata <- rbind(data.frame(v[-ncol(v)],rl_none = 0,v[ncol(v)]),vt))[order(as.Date(testdata$Begindatum),decreasing = T),]
})

res <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind,r),row.names = NULL)
```

On this dataframe, with no luck unfortunately:

```
structure(list(ï..CRM.relatienummer = structure(c("d45248b8974dc4f8ff948779e0fd07e20f304e929ada4e14c0420aebed81e9b5", 
"2ab04e80b3e64601147df977d6054c04ffa80014b3691b25dd1cc8ef85cea06a", 
"2ab04e80b3e64601147df977d6054c04ffa80014b3691b25dd1cc8ef85cea06a", 
"bcf2c99e6dc974380f967204b9623dce2c8a3fad694dc0b4430fcbf77f8f39f3", 
"bcf2c99e6dc974380f967204b9623dce2c8a3fad694dc0b4430fcbf77f8f39f3", 
"f8610cd0237858ac9384d6ba209759ae306860ffabb3f8e6c3d6fc68dbaddc51", 
"e5b8b3f46165e48aec8bbe65ed1cb29d18a0492fbcac44803372f672348459db", 
"c737815b2365b01a8a85c380364a0f721685a131de98cd7790b4d40bb8c4e05b", 
"b9c0272caa8d5d3497d28cce3bda5d3d17c22f18c5f65c5e82c572b410a8ea71", 
"b9c0272caa8d5d3497d28cce3bda5d3d17c22f18c5f65c5e82c572b410a8ea71", 
"539c6c3e604245008daefbe500ff29357bee91f82a7896126bd0f69848524cb7", 
"d361338bed51cb9c8aa73fd8914cbf392f4e05e7b073f637f7b150cf02b89c8c", 
"505d3df3f1298e07aa96073490b72acd2391da06ad4cfbd5a9fbde3a3de79684", 
"826443481cbb5b4e061040d443a0ce8d94322615d8ffae1e68b2ff7d896afcf7", 
"2b59a1ec028c261c0f22cd6a49220dc7cec9a9fb0fabe2296b4ba77a60cfdaae"
), class = c("hash", "sha256")), Begindatum = c("2019-06-14", 
"2019-03-01", "2019-09-02", "2019-03-03", "2019-04-01", "2019-09-21", 
"2019-02-02", "2019-06-11", "2019-02-05", "2019-02-09", "2019-07-24", 
"2019-05-08", "2019-09-27", "2019-08-03", "2019-04-03"), Einddatum = c("2022-04-20", 
"2019-09-01", "2022-04-20", "2019-03-31", "2022-04-20", "2022-04-20", 
"2019-02-14", "2019-07-08", "2019-02-11", "2020-02-08", "2019-09-03", 
"2019-06-18", "2019-11-07", "2019-08-16", "2022-04-20"), Status_dummy = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), relationlength_fixed = c(0, 
184, 961, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), relationlength_promo = c(1041, 
0, 0, 0, 1115, 942, 12, 0, 0, 364, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1113), relationlength_trial = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 41, 41, 41, 13, 0), rl_none = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), fixed_dummy = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), trial_dummy = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), promotional_dummy = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), active_subscr_dummy = c(3, 
0, 5, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3), hashedEmail = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1:1", 
"1:2", "1:3", "1:4", "1:5", "1:6", "1:7", "1:8", "1:9", "1:10", 
"1:11", "1:12", "1:13", "1:14", "1:15"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Joep, welcome to SO. Could you post the results of `dput` (e.g. `dput(df)`) on your example to make it easier to bring into R?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick response. I have the dput for one particular case. My df is slightly different from the one in my example, but still very close. I have added the dput to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is what you are expecting

```
dfs <- split(df,df$ID)

r <- lapply(seq(length(dfs)), function(k){
  v <- dfs[[k]]
  vt <- data.frame(unique(v$ID), 
                   as.character((as.Date(v$Enddate)+1)[-1]), 
                   as.character((as.Date(v$Begindate)-1)[-nrow(v)]), 
                   "none",
                   0,
                   0,
                   0,
                   (as.Date(v$Begindate)-1)[-nrow(v)] - (as.Date(v$Enddate)+1)[-1],
                   NA)
  colnames(vt) <- c(colnames(v)[-ncol(v)],"rl_none",colnames(v)[ncol(v)])
  (df <- rbind(data.frame(v[-ncol(v)],rl_none = 0,v[ncol(v)]),vt))[order(as.Date(df$Begindate),decreasing = T),]
})

res <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind,r),row.names = NULL)
```

which gives

```
> res
  ID  Begindate    Enddate Subscrtype active rl_fixed rl_promo rl_none Productgroup
1  1 2019-08-26 2022-04-20      fixed      1      968        0       0            1
2  1 2019-08-24 2019-08-25       none      0        0        0       1           NA
3  1 2018-08-24 2019-08-23      fixed      0      364        0       0            1
4  1 2016-08-24 2018-08-23       none      0        0        0     729           NA
5  1 2015-08-24 2016-08-23      promo      0        0      364       0            2
6  2 2019-08-26 2019-09-12      fixed      0       17        0       0            1
7  2 2019-08-24 2019-08-25       none      0        0        0       1           NA
8  2 2018-08-24 2019-08-23      fixed      0      364        0       0            1
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Begindate = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("2015-08-24", "2018-08-24", "2019-08-26"
), class = "factor"), Enddate = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("2016-08-23", "2019-08-23", "2019-09-12", "2022-04-20"
), class = "factor"), Subscrtype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("fixed", "promo"), class = "factor"), active = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rl_fixed = c(968L, 364L, 0L, 17L, 364L), rl_promo = c(0L, 
0L, 364L, 0L, 0L), Productgroup = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can't seem to get it to work on the real dataset, even with only 10 observations. It keeps loading endlessly. I have mentioned the dput of my real dataset in my OP.

Edit: I see where it goed wrong, I am going to try to match my real data set with the simplified example.

Comment: @Joep so what is your desired output with the updated `dput` data? I only used your data in your example for the code, since fields in my code are different from your real dataset, so not straightforwardly applicable.....

Comment: I understand! I was hoping that my R knowledge was at least sufficient enough to adjust suggestions made to be applicable to my real dataset, but unfortunately that is not yet the case.

The goal for my full dataset is to add rows in between the current rows that state the periods of time where no subscription was active. The end goal is to aggregate the dataframe and have relation length variables and summed dummy variables indicating the amount of different types of subscriptions and corresponding relation lengths for each user in the dataset.All other columns for the "none" rows can be NA

Comment: I would like to conduct a multinomial logistic regression for the different types of subscription states possible: fixed, promo(, trial) and non active.

Comment: @Joep I saw your test with my code, you forgot to adjust the number of columns in my code according to your dataframe. Mine is for the case with 8 columns, while yours has 13 columns

Comment: I changed it to include all 13 variables. However, I still get no results, not even an error. Even on a sample size of 5 the split takes about half a minute to run. I can't seem to do anything else after this. Opening a dataframe keeps R endlessly loading. The full command keeps loading as well. It does not produce an error or anything. 

Do you know what might be the cause of this? Processor load does not exceed 30% and RAM load does not exceed 60%.

I have edited the code I ran in the OP as well.

Comment: @Joep Sorry that I have no clue which type of problem happens .... I would suggest you write your own functions if you have understood my idea in my solution (or maybe you have better approaches), and I believe that would be the best match for your real data and your goal

Comment: @Joep Also, maybe you can insert `browser()` in your script or function, and debug the program step by step to see where generates the issue....

Comment: I think the issue originates in the split() command. I can't seem to interact in any way with dfs after having run the command. Would there be another way to come up with the same result?

Comment: @Joep you can use `lapply()` to categorize the data frame in terms of unique IDs, but not as efficient as `split()`

Comment: I got a result! It gives me the following error:
 Error in data.frame(unique(v$ï..CRM.relatienummer), as.character((as.Date(v$Einddatum) +  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Comment: @Joep Good work! Keep trying to fix the bugs. My solution is just a hint to you for your task, nobody can help you debug in your exact case. I guess you are getting close to make it.

Comment: Thanks! I have managed to pinpoint some errors and fix them. If I use split(df,factor(df$ID)) instead of split(df,df$ID), it seems to work properly, as in R doesn't get stuck for 20 minutes. However, I receive the error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0, when running the function. If I remove the double brackets at v <- dfs[[k]] it does not give me this error. It then gives me the error that it does not know how to convert v$Enddate to a date format. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: @Joep Sounds great! Sorry that I have no idea about the error in your exact case. My suggestion is that maybe you can take a smaller sample of your dataset that may encounter above errors to debug. Debugging is also a process from which you will learn a lot. Also, which version of `R` are you using? Mine is `R 3.6.1`. I am not sure if there is something incompatible between different versions.

Comment: I am also using 3.6.1. I am going to look into debugging and see what I can find out. It is correct that dfs is from the lift type right? Hence the double brackets at v <- [[k]]. That would mean that something goes wrong with the selection of function k. Thank you for the help!

Comment: the error seems to originate from the date lines. I have had some trouble during the cleanup of the data with the dates as well. If I replace all lines with the date commands with 0's, no error occurs and the function works. It creates the new lines but with 0's where dates and the difference in days between the dates are supposed to be.

Comment: When debugging, it seems like there are 0 observations for the three date variables, hence the differing number of rows: 1, 0 error. I have made some adjustments and can almost get the full line to work, only the bracket commands at the end of the line I can't seem to get to work. The [-1] and [-nrow(v)].                                         
 as.character(as.Date(v$Einddatum, "%Y-%m-%d")+1)[-1], 
as.character(as.Date(v$Begindatum, "%Y-%m-%d")-1)[-nrow(v)],